# R code to identify the same characters in a name and combine the column values

Tags: r

I have a Candidate column, and there are various instances where the Candidate names match but are in different rows, as they differ by lower/upper case, space or symbols. I want to look for all these duplicated rows with the same candidate name, and make it one row. For example: here A.s. Hopingson and A.S. Hopingson are in two different rows, so from the A.S. Hopingson I want to copy three columns to A.s. Hopingson and remove the row with the candidate A.S. Hopingson.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: you can try with library(RecordLinkage), levenshtein distance for strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main issue is to decide which value to keep in case you have different values in separate rows for the same candidate (although this is not the case in your example). Both my suggestions use `tidyverse`.

The first solution that comes up to my mind is to select the row with the lowest number of missing values as your valid entry:

```
(data <- tibble(name = c("A.S. Hopingson",  "a.S. Hopingson",  "A.S.Hopingson"),
               var_1 = c(1, 2, NA),
               var_2 = c(1, NA, NA)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name           var_1 var_2
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 A.S. Hopingson     1     1
2 a.S. Hopingson     2    NA
3 A.S.Hopingson     NA    NA

data %>%
  mutate(name_new = str_replace_all(str_to_lower(name), "[^[:alpha:]]", ""), # create name that consists only of letters
         missing = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% # count missing values per row
  arrange(name_new, missing) %>% # arrange by missing values
  group_by(name_new) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>% # filter for first row (i.e. that with lowest number of missing values
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-name_new, -missing)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  name           var_1 var_2
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 A.S. Hopingson     1     1
```

As you can see, the value `2` for `var_1[2]` is dropped. 
Alternatively, you can select the first non-missing value for each variable and combine these rows:

```
(data <- tibble(name = c("A.S. Hopingson",  "a.S. Hopingson",  "A.S.Hopingson"),
                var_1 = c(1, 1, NA),
                var_2 = c(NA, 2, NA)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name           var_1 var_2
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 A.S. Hopingson     1    NA
2 a.S. Hopingson     1     2
3 A.S.Hopingson     NA    NA

data %>%
  mutate(name_new = str_replace_all(str_to_lower(name), "[^[:alpha:]]", "")) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  gather(key, value, -name_new) %>%
  unique() %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(name_new, key) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(key, value)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  name_new    var_1 var_2
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 ashopingson     1     2
```

In case you need entries from both rows (e.g. because they are both correct), you would have to nest your data or combine the values into a single row.